# std::array initalization with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem initializing a std::array using Visual Studio 2010. I am aware with a modern compiler I may do the following

```
#include <array>

class A
{
    A() : arr({1,2,3,4,5,6}) {}
public:
std::array<float, 6> arr;
};
```

However, Visual Studio 2010 does not allow this (as it does not completly support `C++11`). However, is there an alternate way I am missing?

Comment: I agree with @JesperJuhl, VS2010 is very old when you look at advancements made to the c++ language since VS2010 came out. Consider upgrading to [Visual Studio 2017 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) which is "free for students, open-source contributors, and individuals". Edit : I hope this isn't seen as spam...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I agree. Even I took the pain of moving to C++11 a couple of years ago. It represents a quantum leap in the language.

Comment: I also agree ... unfortunally no option, which makes me sad every day ;)

Comment: @Pi It's your job to convince management of the need to migrate.

Comment: On it. But seems to be a process

Comment: Sorry, guys. There is not a single argument I can make to stay with 2010. So I really cannot (and do not want to) argue :D

Comment: @Pi: Ping me when you've got the migration green-light.

Comment: @Bathsheba Done and done! Thanks for the support!

Comment: Does `A() : arr{{1,2,3,4,5,6}} {}` or `A() : arr{1,2,3,4,5,6} {}`work?

Comment: @NathanOliver Nope. Initilization using {} does not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas not. *Aggregate initialisation* is a C++11 concept and Visual Studio 2010 implements the C++03 standard.

The alternative is to build the array manually in the class constructor.

If you need to be able to create `const` instances of `A`, then build the array in a `static` function say, and copy the contents into `arr`.

Comment: I was afraid that this is the way to go ;)  Thanks

Comment: Minor correction: 2010 implements C++03 and some C++11 :)